# onChanged value not picking up by setState Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am creating a sign up page with multiple account types option. The app is simple so its without any state I'm only going with simple old setState but I am passing my changed value to setState in my stateful widget but its the first time happening to me flutter isn't picking up the value in setState. I've scratched my head for too many hours but still the same issue. My flutter version is 2.5. The GFRadio Button setState is the one creating issue. Also if I use simple dart radio button or RadioListTile they also are creating the same issue

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:getwidget/colors/gf_color.dart';
import 'package:getwidget/components/radio/gf_radio.dart';
import 'package:getwidget/size/gf_size.dart';

class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SignUpPage> createState() => _SignUpPageState();
}

class _SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
  bool _obscureText = true;
  int groupValue = 0;
  void _togglePasswordStatus() {
    setState(() {
      _obscureText = !_obscureText;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                    "assets/loginpage.png",
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 250,
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
                          child: Text("New\nAccount",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 34, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                        ),
                        Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  right: 40,
                                ),
                                child: Image.asset("assets/camera.png")),
                            Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 40, top: 70),
                                child: Text("Add Image")),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 350,
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
                          child: GFRadio(
                            size: GFSize.SMALL,
                            value: 2,
                            groupValue: groupValue,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                groupValue = value;
                              });
                            },
                            inactiveIcon: null,
                            activeBorderColor: GFColors.SUCCESS,
                            radioColor: GFColors.SUCCESS,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                            right: 40,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 400,
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Username",
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.person,
                            color: Color(0xFFCF776B),
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFCF776B)),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFCF776B)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 470,
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                      child: TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Mobile Number",
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.phone,
                            color: Color(0xFFCF776B),
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFCF776B)),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFCF776B)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 540,
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                      child: TextField(
                        obscureText: _obscureText,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: "Password",
                          prefixIcon: Icon(
                            Icons.lock,
                            color: Color(0xFFCF776B),
                          ),
                          suffixIcon: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                _obscureText
                                    ? Icons.visibility
                                    : Icons.visibility_off,
                              ),
                              onPressed: _togglePasswordStatus,
                              color: Color(0xFFCF776B)),
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFCF776B)),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFCF776B)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 620,
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          // Navigator.push(
                          //     context,
                          //     MaterialPageRoute(
                          //         builder: (context) => SignUpPage()));
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          width: 180,
                          height: 60,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xFFCF776B),
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: Color(0xFFCF776B),
                              ),
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40))),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text("Sign Up",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.white)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 700,
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Change Password",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                            color: Color(0xFFCF776B),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: u can use TextEditingController

Comment: Can you please give any example regarding it if you have any I am confused

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood the `GFRadio` widget here:

```
GFRadio(
                            size: GFSize.SMALL,
                            value: 2,
                            groupValue: groupValue,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                groupValue = value;
                              });
                            },
                            inactiveIcon: null,
                            activeBorderColor: GFColors.SUCCESS,
                            radioColor: GFColors.SUCCESS,
                          ),
```

The `groupValue` is the created to determine which radio buttons are there in this group, every radio buttons in this group wil have the same `groupValue`. And the `value` is made to differ a radio button from the others in the same group. Let's say you  have 3 radio buttons for users to choose their gender(male, female, gay ;) ), the code may look like this:

```
int _value = 0;
Row(
                  children: [
                    GFRadio(
                      value: 0,
                      groupValue: 1,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _value = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    GFRadio(
                      value: 1,
                      groupValue: 1,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _value = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    GFRadio(
                      value: 2,
                      groupValue: 1,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _value = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

So as you can see, the thing that need to change in the `setState` method is the `_value`, not the `groupValue`. Your code should be changed to:

```
//int groupValue = 0;
//replace the above line with the below line:
int _value = 0;
```

And in `setState` method in GFRadio:

```
    setState(() {
 //groupValue = value; replace this line with below line
_value = value;
                                  });
```

I am terrible at explaining so if you don't understand, just comment !

Comment: Didn't worked. If I remove groupValue GFRadio says its compulsory to add and with the value stuff its still the same

Comment: Can you provide the error log in the question ?